# Changing the base URL for Rails 3 development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, webrick

I know I'm going to deploy to an environment with my application running with a base URL which looks like this:

```
http://someserver/mydepartment/myapp
```

My development environment is set up to use the default Rails configuration, which looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/myapp
```

I'd like to model this deployment path in my development environment.  That is, I'd like to develop with a base URL which looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/mydepartment/myapp
```

That way, I can make all my URLs relative to "/" and they will work in both environments.

How can I change it so my application will live at this path in my development environment?

Solutions I've found, but don't work for me:

- Setting the `scope` in `routes.rb` doesn't seem to work for the static content in `public`.
- Using Apache's rewriting capabilities. I don't want to install Apache on my development box. Ideally the solution would work with WEbrick, though I seem to have Mongrel mostly working as well (there are some problems with Mongrel and Ruby 1.9.2).
- Setting `relative_url_root` and similar suggestions which don't work with Rails 3.
- Dynamically generating CSS/JavaScript and adjusting the paths to compensate between development and production environments.

Comment: What Operating system are you using for Development? mac/linux/windows

Comment: My development OS is Windows.

Comment: How is it being deployed in production? I'd try and do that locally.

Comment: They use Passenger, which doesn't run on Windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try mapping your rails app rack config to a different base_uri.
All you need to do is wrap the existing 'run' command in a map block

try doing this in your rails '**config.ru**' file:

```
map '/mydepartment' do
    run Myapp::Application
end
```

Now when you 'rails server' the app should be at **localhost:3000/mydepartment** . 
Not sure if this will give you the desired outcome, but worth a try.

Comment: I had to use "map '/mydepartment/myapp' do", i.e. adding "/myapp", but this did the trick. Thanks so much for your help, Barlow!

Comment: Hi @Barlow, I have a similar situation, but I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically map a Rails app at run-time? I've created a question for this and would appreciate any response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060062/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-the-base-path-in-rails-depending-on-how-it

Comment: Just a note, this doesn't work in Rails 4. The views can be found, but the assets still get mapped to the root when using the asset url/path helpers. The server can't find the assets at the root url, though.

Comment: @Jason What should I do for rails 4? =D

Answer (score 6):

Here’s how you can deploy a Rails 3.1 app to a subdirectory in Apache, replacing `config.action_controller.relative_url_root` which no longer exists.

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
scope 'my_subdir' do
  # all resources and routes go here
end
```

In your Apache configuration file:

```
Alias /my_subdir /var/www/my_subdir/public
<Location /my_subdir>
  SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/my_subdir"
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/my_subdir
</Location>
```

And it should work, including automatically pointing all your assets to `/my_subdir`.

Comment: This worked for me using Rails 3.2.12 without modifying my routes.rb