# Rails 3: Scopes: Routing: JS/CSS helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I want to run my Rails application in a different scope so that I can deploy it in a war file (mydepartment.war) which will share a Tomcat instance with another Java app WAR. The [solution I chose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558900/changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3-development) was to modify the rackup file (/config.ru).

```
map '/mydepartment' do
   run Myapp::Application
end
```

When I do this, my base URL becomes **http://localhost:3000/mydepartment** instead of just **http://localhost:3000**. The application runs fine, but it doesn't download CSS/JS specified by stylesheet and script helpers.

However, when I try to include stylesheets and Javascript using helpers, such as

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tags :defaults %>
```

The URLs they generate include **localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery.js** instead of **localhost:3000/mydepartment/javascripts/jquery.js**. I actually tried typing the latter in the browser, and the sheet downloads fine.

How can I coax the Rails Javascript/CSS helpers to download files in the new scope without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not on rails 3.1:

Add this to your `config/environments/production.rb` (if on production mode):

`config.action_controller.asset_path = proc { |path| "/mydepartment#{path}" }`

Comment: I'm on Rails 3.0.10. I tried this and restarted my server. Didn't work!

Comment: sorry my fault, forgot the action_controller part ;) see my edited answer