# How to mount Rails 3.x app at a prefix with Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm using Rails 3.x with Passenger and I'm having trouble understanding how to correctly prefix the app such that it understands,
- how to route urls that start with the prefix
- how to generate paths such that they are prefixed with /foo

Others have asked this (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root)), however, I still don't seem to have the whole picture.

Prior to Passenger, I was starting mongrels with *RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT* which initializes ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root which enables Rails to generate asset paths with the correct prefix. In addition, I was scoping all my routes with, like so,

```
    MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
      scope ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root do
        ...
      end
    end
```

which enables Rails to route and generate urls correctly.

When switching to Passenger, I set *passenger_base_uri* (in nginx-speak) as described by Passenger docs. Passenger then sets relative_url_root which enables Rails to generate asset paths. Passenger also seems to strip the prefix from the url before passing it to Rails. Therefore, I have to remove the scoping of routes to have Rails route urls. BUT removing the scope also prevents Rails from correctly generating urls.

So, how can I have Rails generate the correct paths? What am I missing?

Comment: This Answer might help you out. Can be easier to do this with Rack.
[changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558900/changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3-development/5659238#5659238)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this using [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) + [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/).  From `config/routes.rb`:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do

  scope '/abc' do
    resources :projects
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end

end
```

Accessed via:

```
http://myhost/abc/
```