# How to write a redirect that uses relative_url_root if defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I'm currently using Ruby on Rails 3.2.8 and have this redirect in **config/routes.rb**:

```
root :to => redirect("/home/index.html")
```

which works fine for redirecting **http://localhost:3000/** to **http://localhost:3000/home/index.html** in development. But in my test environment, I'm using a proxy and a subpath, setting **relative_url_root** in **config/environments/test.rb** like this:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/testpath'
```

So I would expect a redirect from **http://testdomain.com/testpath** to **http://testdomain.com/testpath/home/index.html** but instead it redirects to **http://testdomain.com/home/index.html**.

How can I change my redirect statement to use relative_url_root in case it is set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that the method is deprecated, but it [does seem to be broken](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4308). You should be able to work around the issue with something like this:

```
root :to => redirect("#{ Rails.application.config.action_controller.relative_url_root }/home/index.html")
```

It might be worth pointing out that this bug is not reproducible on my machine (I am using thin), the code you posed works as intended.

Comment: If it works in thin, are you using it in a proxy mode to rails? My setup is an Apache proxying from **http://testdomain.com/testpath** to **http://localhost:3000**.

Comment: I am not, I'm just running it for local development.

Answer (score 0):

The `relative_url_root` method seems to have been deprecated.  See this SO post for a Rails 3 solution: [Changing the base URL for Rails 3 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558900/changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3-development)