# Cannot locate assets after changing base url with map (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, base-url

Please refer to the original question [Changing the base URL for Rails 3 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558900/changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3-development). My application has to run at `/a/special/route` in relation to the host. I used the map solution, which works for the view.

In config.ru:

```
map '/mydepartment' do
  run Myapp::Application
end
```

(The scope answer doesn't work. I get undefined method scope for Main Object)

But the assets are not resolved like the comments indicate. I tried using a bunch of different prefix to no avail:
1. `config.assets.prefix = '/a/special/route/assets'`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.js"):
```

2. `config.assets.prefix = '/a/special/route/'`

   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/paginate.js")
3. Using scope:

   scope '/a/special/route/' do

   resources :channels

   end

`undefined method 'scope' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Do your assets have to be served under the same 'base url'?  If they don't, I would avoid doing this at all cost.  Adding a parent scope to the routes is the way to go.  Can you post the actual exception you are getting and your routes file with the scope that was causing the issue?

Comment: `config.assets.prefix = '/a/special/route/assets'` should load them where you expect, what error are you getting on the request/what path is rails trying to load?

Comment: @tagCincy No, the url of the assets doesn't matter. I'm just trying to get them to show.
@ JonathanBender I added some error logs for reference.

Comment: @myfashionhub  I am assuming that you are adding the `scope` block inside the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block of routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

@tagCincy No I didn't. So when I do use scope correctly inside `Rails.application.routes.draw`, the app can't find any template....

Anyway my assets problem seems to be more complicated than I thought. We use Varnish to serve the app at `another-hostname.com/a/special/route`. And the requests for assets are made relative to `another-hostname.com/assets/` while they are located in `actual-hostname.com/assets/`. So I used this in application.rb as a hack fix: `config.action_controller.asset_host = "actual-hostname.com"`