# Changing the base URL for Capybara Acceptance Tests

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capybara, rack, minitest

I am developing a sinatra based web application and I extensively use tests to make sure that everything is working before deployment. As testing frameworks I use minitest::specs and capybara with webkit.

My problem is that after deployment my application runs with a base url like this:

```
http://cool.server.net/to-the-application/
```

But during tests capybara assumes a clean base-url with a path to `/` not to `to-the-application/`. This means I can't test to find bugs which relate to forgetting to set the base-url within links and actions.

For dry testing I followed [Changing the base URL for Rails 3 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558900/changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3-development) and modified my `config.ru`, but I haven't found any way to get capybara to use a different base.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I am interested in changing in testing the application as if it was not residing in the root of the server URL. Edited the question to (hopefully) reflect that more clearly...

Answer (score 2):

If using the rack_test driver the hostname is completely ignored so changing it isn't going to do anything.  If using a different driver you can specify

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://cool.server.net"
```

Note that cool.server.net would generally need to resolve to 127.0.0.1 since thats where Capybara binds the app being tested.

Update: After thinking about this I'm not sure that is what you wanted.  If what you want is for Capybara to mount your app under `/to-the-application` then you're going to have to create your own app object which you assign to `Capybara.app` - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.13_stable/lib/capybara/rails.rb#L4 for how Capybara currently mounts the app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will dig into the capybara app object. I had hoped somebody else alread did that and came back to tell about it... 8)